# Java - How to get an Integer associated with a String in a HashMap

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to know how to get the Integer that is associated with the String in the HashMap people:

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> people;

public int getAssociatedInt(Person p){
return (The thing I do not know how to get);
}
```

I already tried people.get();, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: `people.put(1, "Hello"); people.get(1);`

Comment: Without a reverse `Map` (which you could maintain alongside `people`), I think you would have to loop through the `Integer`'s in the key set and see if any of the values match this person's`String` value.

Comment: @Kon He wants the reverse, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a map that maps `Integer`s to `String`s, not the other way around. To find the (potentially multiple) `Integer` keys associated with a given `String` value, you can loop over the `Map`s `entrySet()`:

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> e : people.entrySet())
    if (e.getValue().equals(value))
        return e.getKey();
```

However, the method above doesn't deal with multiple keys mapping to the same value. If you want to handle that, you can keep a list of target keys and add to the list instead of return in the body of the `if`-statement.

An alternate method would be to maintain a "reverse" map that maps the strings to the integers, and then simply query that.

Comment: And I really think the correct way to implement this _is_ to maintain a reverse map.  It just depends on whether memory is an issue or not--if not, then we should just keep the extra map (and doubling the memory usage is unlikely to put you over the limit unless you are already close).

Comment: ...but I do notice that `people` is declared `public` which means it technically wouldn't be possible to maintain such map.

Comment: @Jared Yes I also think in the general case a reverse map would do. However, it might not always be so simple (e.g. if multiple `Integer`s refer to a single `String`).

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
public Integer getAssociatedInt(Person p){
    for(final int i : people.keySet())
        if(people.get(i).equals(p.toString()))
            return i;
    // else no key found, return no key (null is the only way to capture this).
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> people;

public int getAssociatedInt(Person p){
    int indexOfPerson = -1;
    if (p != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); ++i) {
            if (p.equals(people.get(i)) {
                indexOfPerson = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return indexOfPerson;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you prefer `return indexOfPerson;` over `return -1;`? (also, I think you're missing the closing brace for `if (p != null)`)

Comment: Probably just wrote the code in haste.  You were correct; thank you.